# bootstrap carousel doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use bootstrap carousel with a little fixes.
I need to show three elements, and move the one.
I tried to repeat code from http://www.bootply.com/94444
but my code doesn't work http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/
The first element moved one, and the all stops.

In console I get an error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined`

What's wrong? Why my code doesn't work? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/

Comment: This is not the code. Also, you should provide your code in your question instead of using the links which could be inaccessible in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it has to do with the carousel but in your javascript file main.js, the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined' has to do with this. It might not be able to find the 'li' element in 'this'. Check if these are the correct variables, and if 'li' actually exists in this' context.

```
var lis = this.find('li')

lis.slice(i, i + 3).addClass('visible');
```